# NSDecimalNumber to unsignedLongLong - wrong value

Tags: iphone, core-foundation

Here is code:

```
NSNumber* number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString :@"11111111111111111"];
NSLog(@"%@ = %lld", number, [number unsignedLongLongValue]);
```

And I get output:

```
11111111111111111 = 11111111111111112
```

Is it known bug or I do something wrong?

**UPDATE:**
bug reported: https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/3/wo/Stnn5Aaocknzx52c64zbN0/5.83.28.0.9

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is that you are using NSNumber's `-longLongValue` method on an NSDecimalNumber.  NSDecimalNumber stores a high-precision representation of the number internally as a decimal, but NSNumber just keeps it as an IEEE 754 double precision floating-point value.  If I recall correctly, if you use the standard NSNumber superclass methods on an NSDecimalNumber, the internal number is first converted to a double, which can introduce binary floating-point artifacts like this.

As neoneye suggests, a way around this might be to use an NSString as an intermediary.  For example:

```
NSDecimalNumber* number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString :@"11111111111111111"];
double number2 = [@"11111111111111111" doubleValue];

NSLog(@"%@ = %lld = %f", number, [[number descriptionWithLocale:nil] longLongValue], number2);
```

Will produce the result `11111111111111111 = 11111111111111111 = 11111111111111112.000000`, showing both the correct result from the decimal number extraction and the error that happens when this number is temporarily stored in a double.

Comment: "If I recall correctly, if you use the standard NSNumber superclass methods on an NSDecimalNumber, the internal number is first converted to a double, which can introduce floating-point artifacts like this"

Where did you get this information? It sounds strange and I hardly believe in it. In most cases we work with instance via NSNumber interface and we should not think which concrete subclass was used to construct this instance.

Comment: @iKiR - There was some discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479100/cocoa-ive-discovered-what-i-think-is-a-bug-with-nsdecimalnumber , which points to Marcus' comments here: http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/23/cocoa-tutorial-dont-be-lazy-with-nsdecimalnumber-like-me/ , but that doesn't exactly state this case.  It may have been somewhere in the cocoa-dev mailing list archives that I found this, back when I ran into a similar problem.  Yes, it is odd, and I think I filed a bug report on it back then.  I'd recommend filing another one yourself.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I filed a bug couple minutes ago: https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/3/wo/Stnn5Aaocknzx52c64zbN0/5.83.28.0.9