# Incompatible Objective-C types initializing 'struct NSNumber *', expected 'struct NSDecimalNumber *'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uislider

I have the below method in my project, and I get a compiler warning: `Incompatible Objective-C types initializing 'struct NSNumber *', expected 'struct NSDecimalNumber *` on the first line:

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(id)sender {
    // HERE IS WHERE THE WARNING OCCURS:
    NSDecimalNumber *tempNumber = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:[self.slider value]];

    NSDecimalNumberHandler *roundingStyle = [NSDecimalNumberHandler decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:NSRoundBankers
                                                                                                   scale:3 
                                                                                        raiseOnExactness:NO
                                                                                         raiseOnOverflow:NO 
                                                                                        raiseOnUnderflow:NO 
                                                                                     raiseOnDivideByZero:NO];
    NSDecimalNumber *roundedNumber = [tempNumber decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:roundingStyle];
    self.slider.value = [roundedNumber floatValue];


    // Set up the percentage formatter
    NSNumberFormatter *percentFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [percentFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle];
    [percentFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:1];
    [percentFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:1];

    // Find the label to update
    NSUInteger onlyRow[] = {0, 0};
    NSIndexPath *onlyRowPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:onlyRow length:2];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:onlyRowPath];
    UILabel *theLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kLabelFieldTag];

    NSNumber *theNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.slider.value];
    theLabel.text = [percentFormatter stringFromNumber:theNumber];

    [percentFormatter release];
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `numberWithFloat` is said (in the header) to always returns an NSNumber object. Sending the method to a subclass still returns an NSNumber object. I don't know NSDecimalNumber in detail, but I see several approaches to the problem here:

1. (**dirty**) you might try to cast the result to `(NSDecimalNumber *)` and see if it works
2. (clean) use one of NSDecimalNumbers initializers, like [`+ decimalNumberWithString:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDecimalNumber/decimalNumberWithString:)
3. (best) Shift your method to use NSNumber and a NSNumberFormatter only, this supports different rounding behaviors as well

Comment: method 1 works, (`[[NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:2] class]` is NSDecimalNumber)

Comment: Okay, good to hear, but I'd still stick to a different method. The static cast in the NSNumber headers is definitely a problem here...

Comment: @cobbal - Actually, that can introduce floating-point issues, so I'd recommend number 2 on the list if you wish to avoid this.  See this question for an example of what can go wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479100/cocoa-ive-discovered-what-i-think-is-a-bug-with-nsdecimalnumber

Answer (score 2):

`numberWithFloat` method returns a NSNumber instance. Just typecasting it to NSDecimalNUmber might resolve the warning.

```
NSDecimalNumber *tempNumber = (NSDecimalNumber *)[NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:[self.slider value]];
```